# Is it possible to get a session variable for a jsp without an ActionBean?

Tags: session, stripes

I have map stored in session (MyActionBeanContext) that needs to be retrieved for header.jsp

However, since header.jsp is embedded on many other jsp's, it is not connected with any ActionBean so I can't simply call ${actionbean.context.map}

Is there a way at getting the map from my header.jsp? If not, what would be the best way to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer is to use ${sessionScope.map}